# Data still being calculated after being suppressed on Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum, suppress

I have created a Formula Field to calculate the average time of idle.
However, the data appears to be suspiciously calculating data that I have suppressed.
How should I rewrite the command so it doesn't calculate the suppressed data
I am using Crystal Report 11 with DB2.

*Suppress* formula:

```
{@CUSTOMER DROP MAX AMOUNT} = 0
```

`customer drop max amount` formula field as:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
IF GroupName ({@DROP CUSTOMER}) = "ASHLADVNC" AND GroupName ({@TRAILER CHARGE GROUP}) = "INTCNEWNC" THEN
    IF {#COUNTER} <= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
ELSE
    1
```

I have a *running total field* summarizing field `days idle` as:

```
CurrentDateTime - {TRAILER_CUSTOMER_ZONE.IDLE_SINCE}
```

But I actually use this formula within my report `avg idle days yard` as:

```
IF ISNULL({#Avg Idle Days Yard}) THEN "N/A" ELSE TOTEXT({#Avg Idle Days Yard})
```

Comment: Suppressed data is only visually hidden, it is always counted for summaries. You must include your condition to skip suppressed data within your formula.

Comment: How you are suppressing data? Using formula or duplicate suppress?

Comment: a formula where "Max Customer Drop Zone <> 0" and max customer drop zone is also within the formula field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppressed data is only visually hidden, it always accounts for summaries, running totals. To skip suppressed data, condition must be applied within the formula.

Change the *evaluate* mode of *running total field* `days idle` or `avg idle days yard` (whichever is your base formula to calculate total and average) to `Use a formula`

Then set the *formula condition* as `{@CUSTOMER DROP MAX AMOUNT} <> 0;`. Suppressed records will be skipped as per your formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can fry using running total

1. Select the field that need to be summarized
2. In evaluate use the opposite conditon like if in supress you use =, then in evaluate use <>
3. Set reset according to your requirement...if there is only detail then set reset part to never

Comment: I did that and I receive "boolean is required here"

Comment: After deleting the previous field and simply putting in <> the fields now say true or false

Comment: Didn't understood your question

Comment: added more details im sorry

Comment: Where is your supression logic